# SQL query to include/exclude an item line based on the status of other lines in the order

Tags: sql, sql-server

***UPDATE NO 2***

With very important inputs from Solution 1 and Solution 2, I finally have a sql that does exactly what it needs to. Thanks to both users, appreciate their assistance. I wish I could mark both solution as answers, but considering the base of my query is from @papo's solution and also that it is very short compared to the other solution, I mark that as my answer.

Final working sql

```
SELECT CNumber, Item, Status
FROM WEBS t1
WHERE (     ((t1.Item IN ('SHIPEXP', 'SHIPPING', 'SHIPINT', 'SHIPBOND', 'GIFT WRAP')) 
                AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM WEBS
                                WHERE CNumber = t1.CNumber
                                      AND ( Status NOT IN (1, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17)
                                          )
                            )
            )
        OR 
                ( Status NOT IN (1, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17)
                )
      )
AND CNumber = 12140836
```

---

***UPDATE***

I have a final query that looks as below: This is the solution that I accepted as the answer. This has been modified to suit my table structure and other clauses.

The issue is query fails on SCENARIO 2 as described before i.e. display no results when all items completed. Scenario 1 succeeds.

```
SELECT t.ItemCode
     , t.ItemStatus
  FROM WEBORDER_STATUS t
 WHERE t.CustOrderNumber = 12140799
   AND  ( ( ( t.ItemCode <> 'SHIPEXP' OR t.ItemCode <> 'SHIPPING' OR t.ItemCode <> 'SHIPINT' OR t.ItemCode <> 'SHIPBOND' OR t.ItemCode <> 'GIFT WRAP'
            ) 
                AND ( t.ItemStatus <> 11 AND t.ItemStatus <> 12 AND 
                      t.ItemStatus <> 1 AND t.ItemStatus <> 13 AND 
                      t.ItemStatus <> 14 AND t.ItemStatus <> 15 AND 
                      t.ItemStatus <> 16 AND t.ItemStatus <> 17
                    )
          )
        OR 
          ( (t.ItemCode = 'SHIPEXP' OR t.ItemCode = 'SHIPPING' OR t.ItemCode = 'SHIPINT' OR t.ItemCode = 'SHIPBOND' OR t.ItemCode = 'GIFT WRAP') 
             AND EXISTS
              ( SELECT 1
                   FROM WEBORDER_STATUS s
                WHERE s.CustOrderNumber = t.CustOrderNumber
                   AND (t.ItemCode <> 'SHIPEXP' OR t.ItemCode <> 'SHIPPING' OR t.ItemCode <> 'SHIPINT' OR t.ItemCode <> 'SHIPBOND' OR t.ItemCode <> 'GIFT WRAP') 
                       AND ( t.ItemStatus <> 11 OR t.ItemStatus <> 12 OR 
                             t.ItemStatus <> 1 OR t.ItemStatus <> 13 OR 
                             t.ItemStatus <> 14 OR t.ItemStatus <> 15 OR 
                             t.ItemStatus <> 16 OR t.ItemStatus <> 17
                           )
              )
          )
       )
```

---

I need assistance in writing a SQL query using standard Tsql on sql server.

I have a situation where i need to select items from a table based on their status.

Lines for order number 111 are as follows: Itemcode Shipping will always be Completed.

**Scenario 1:**

> ItemCode----   Status
>
> 123      -----------Inprogress
>
> 456      -----------Inprogress
>
> 789      -----------Completed
>
> SHIPPING ----Completed

**Expected Result** (Exclude completed items, but include shipping item as all orders will have SHIPPING)

> 123      -----------Inprogress
>
> 456      -----------Inprogress
>
> SHIPPING ----Completed

---

**Scenario 2:**

> ItemCode----   Status
>
> 123      -----------Completed
>
> 456      -----------Completed
>
> 789      -----------Completed
>
> SHIPPING ----Completed

**Expected Result** (Exclude completed items, but as all items are completed Exclude SHIPPING as well)

> No results (as all items are completed)

Any help or direction is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It would be useful to see what you have already tried.  What is your current attempt?

Comment: do you have values like `SHIPPING` in your `ItemCode` column ?

Comment: @M.Ali Yes SHIPPING is an Itemcode and every order will have a SHIPPING item code in the order lines.

Comment: @aMazing: I believe you want to replace the OR with AND when you negate (invert) the predicates. (See the followup I added to the bottom of my answer.) Those tests can be more concisely expressed using the `IN` and `NOT IN` operators, e.g. `t.ItemStatus IN (11,12,1,13,...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only show the SHIPPING row when there are uncompleted items for this order. Show the other items only when they are not completed.

```
SELECT OrderNo, ItemCode, Status
FROM table1 t1
WHERE ((ItemCode = 'SHIPPING'
    AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1
         WHERE OrderNo = t1.OrderNo
         AND Status != 'Completed'))
OR Status != 'Completed')
AND OrderNo = 111;
```

Comment: Can you show me where do I add the where clause for ordernumber = 111 as I am only interested in lines for that order. Currently it will return for all orders. thanks

Comment: Can simply be added to the end. Just make sure to use brackets around the original clause.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use an EXISTS predicate to test whether there are any rows (other than 'SHIPPING')  that aren't status 'COMPLETED' to conditionally return the 'SHIPPING' row.

For example:

```
SELECT t.ItemCode
     , t.Status
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.OrderNumber = 111 
   AND (  ( t.ItemCode <> 'SHIPPING' AND t.Status <> 'Completed' 
          )
       OR ( t.ItemCode = 'SHIPPING' AND EXISTS
              ( SELECT 1
                  FROM mytable s
                 WHERE s.OrderNumber = t.OrderNumber
                   AND s.ItemCode <> 'SHIPPING'
                   AND s.Status <> 'Completed'
              )
           )
       )
```

NOTES

The predicate `t.OrderNumber = 111` isn't necessary. This could be omitted, or be whatever other criteria. (I assumed your query would have that as a predicate because the examples you showed omitted an OrderNumber column. If you omit that predicate, it's likely you'd want to return OrderNumber in the select list.)

This:

```
          ( t.ItemCode <> 'SHIPPING' AND t.Status <> 'Completed' 
          )
```

gets all the rows that aren't SHIPPING that have a status other than completed. (This might not match any rows, as in the second scenario.)

This:

```
          ( t.ItemCode = 'SHIPPING' AND EXISTS
              ( SELECT 1
                  FROM mytable s
                 WHERE s.OrderNumber = t.OrderNumber
                   AND s.ItemCode <> 'SHIPPING'
                   AND s.Status <> 'Completed'
              )
          )
```

gets the SHIPPING row only if there's another row in the table, for the same OrderNumber and a status that's not 'Completed'. If there isn't a row returned by the subquery, the `EXISTS` predicate returns FALSE, so the entire expression evaluates to FALSE, so the SHIPPING row will not be returned.

Add an `ORDER BY` clause to get the rows returned in a specific sequence. To get the SHIPPING row last, e.g

```
 ORDER BY CASE t.ItemCode WHEN 'SHIPPING' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, t.ItemCode
```

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Based on your updated query, note that the "negation" of this:

```
    (a = 'b' OR a = 'c')
```

would be:

```
    (a <> 'b' AND a <> 'c')
```

Note that the `OR` needs to be replaced with an `AND`.  If you work through a test case, for example, consider a row with `itemCode = 'SHIPEXP'`. We know that if this is true, then `itemCode <> 'SHIPPING'` will also be true.

Similarly, the expression:

```
( ItemStatus <> 11 OR ItemStatus <> 12 )
```

Will return TRUE for any non-null value of `ItemStatus`. (If the value is 11, then `ItemStatus <> 12` will be TRUE. That would result in ( FALSE OR TRUE ), which would return TRUE. The same goes for a value of `12`...  ( TRUE OR FALSE ) will return TRUE. I think what you want is to return a FALSE. To get that, the predicates would need to be AND'd together.

I believe that's the crux of the behavior you are seeing with your query. You've got predicates returning TRUE when you expect them to return FALSE.

---

An equivalent (and more concise) way to express the predicate on `ItemCode` (to see if the value matches one of a list of values) would be:

```
t.ItemCode IN ('SHIPEXP','SHIPPING','SHIPINT','SHIPBOND','GIFT WRAP')
```

Similarly, a check of `ItemStatus` could be expressed as:

```
t.ItemStatus NOT IN (11,12,1,13,14,15,16,17)
```

Note that with a `NOT IN`, the inequality tests are AND'ed together rather than OR'd together. So that's equivalent to:

```
t.ItemStatus <> 11 AND t.itemStatus <> 12 AND ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for your first scenario:

```
SELECT ItemCode, Status FROM Your_Table WHERE Status!= 'Completed' AND ItemCode !='SHIPPING'
```

For your second scenario may be need a store procedure or a case with nested queries

Comment: Thanks. A single query should be able to handle both scenarios.